# How can we display images in laravel using path?

Tags: laravel

Currently working on a small project, where i am facing a problem in displaying images in laravel tried but can't resolved the issue , I think the problem is in the url, Kindly help me in resolving this issue.
following are some links which will clear my statement.

https://github.com/parvez-git/real-estate/issues/7

I posted my issue on github, and didn't find an active response.

Comment: Please put the contents of your actual question and the things you attempted in this post instead of just a link to another question

Comment: also make sure you're putting the images in the correct public folder

Comment: have you storage:link? the storage path should be in public folder

Answer (score 0):

If you use in style sheet then use like this

```
background: url("{{ url('') }}/Your_Image_Path/spinner-grey.png"); //Like /stogare/app/public/../../
```

If you use in blade view use like this

```
<img src="{{ url('') }}/UI/Diamond/frontend/images_theme/arrow-up-pd.png" alt="arrow">
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you do `php artisan storage:link`. If done, delete the storage folder in public folder and run the command again.

the storage file access should be done using filesystems
ex:

```
<img src="{{ Storage::disk('DISK_NAME')->url('YOUR_FILE_NAME') }}" />
```